# What is current nodejs version

Tags: node.js

I don't understand what is really latest Nodejs version. When I write `nodejs -v` on my ubuntu machine I get `v0.10.25` but on site nodejs.org is written latest version as v5.5.0 So can some explain these two numbers? Thanks

Comment: Did you install the latest one on your ubuntu machine?

Comment: `v5.5.0` is the latest version and you have `v0.10.25` installed.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: Yes I hope I installed latest one, but it looks is really very old one... Am I really 5 version back?

Comment: v0.10.x is old..if you can upgrade to either the latest 4.x.x or 5.x.x. As for the difference between the two see the succinct description on the nodejs homepage https://nodejs.org/en/ v4 (LTS i.e. Long Term Support) - 'mature and dependable' or v5 - 'Latest Features'

Comment: OK thanks a lot I need to reinstall it ASAP.

Comment: You are not alone, I still don't understand this ish. I have latest NodeJS, but I still have v0.10.25 as a version. Super confusing

Answer (score 0):

You aren't 5 major releases back. Node was previously forked into io.js due to differences of opinion from the Joyent team (that manages Node).

They recently reconciled and merged the codebase. The latest version of io.js was at 3.x.x and the latest version of Node was 0.12.x so the new release was 4.x.x

You should probably still update though.